# Php & Sql Injection - UTF8 POC

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

There is a lot of talk about how addslashes and mysql_real_escape function are not safe to prevent injections. The truth is even the big frameworks or CMSs like Wordpress are using this functions and they do a god job so far.

I know there are some particular scenarios when using GBK charset, or utf8_decode can be used to inject some sql code, or some simple examples like `1' OR 1 --` that can be used when there is a simple where involved.

However, after a bit of research it seems very hard to inject something into a simple query with addslashes or mysql_real_escape used if the charset is UTF-8 and let's admit it, this is the most common scenario.

So, given this newbie script, pls provide a sql injection POC ( remember UTF-8 charset )

```
$mysql['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
$mysql['password'] = addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username = '{$mysql['username']}'
AND password = '{$mysql['password']}'";
```

Update - I just need a simple example not a full disclosure of the process. Even a link from google might work.

Comment: 2 bookmarks and 2 close votes ? Any reasons ?

Comment: Good question, but what I would like to know is: Why *not* simply use `mysql_real_escape_string` if there's even a remote theoretical possibility that `addslashes` is not good enough (not to mention prepared statements et al)?

Comment: I told you this is completely wrong site for such questions. No kidding. That's because most people never think of the question (not to say of the problem behind the question) but rather tend to issue some sort of piece of knowledge which they think is connected to the question. Look, this guy asked similar question and got no good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448441/ however, it contains some sort of answer to your question too

Comment: I understand you opinion Col. Shrapnel but last time you gave me the right answer :)

Comment: Lol, like I said! The guy got the bounty for his useless rant :)

Comment: @col. I'm not sorry for that. People will see the answer and will get the point. I didn't expect a POC.

Answer (score 11):

**Update 2**:

[After further research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secur/5415037#5415037), MySQL versions prior to **5.0.77** may be vulnerable to the GBK issue when combined with `SET NAMES` alone.  It was earlier believed that only 5.0.22 and earlier were vulnerable.

This means that if you are using PHP versions *prior* to 5.2, in which `mysql_set_charset` / `mysqli_set_charset` were introduced, your code may be vulnerable under specific, well-crafted conditions.

If you're stuck on PHP 5.1, please ensure that you are using MySQL 5.0.77 or later.  5.0.77 is "only" two years old, but has been pushed into the repositories for RHEL/CentOS 5.x, the more popular distribution stuck with the 5.0.x series of MySQL and 5.1.x series of PHP.

Get upgrading, people!

---

*Update 1*: [Another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken) has uncovered the source of the GBK thing: [A bugfix in MySQL 5.0.22](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/news-5-0-22.html).  Versions earlier than this are *severely* vulnerable when using anything other than `mysql_real_escape_string` *combined with* [`mysql_set_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) *instead of* just `SET NAMES`.  The mysqli equivilent is named [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

There does not appear to be an equivilent of `mysql_set_charset` in PDO.  This may be either because it can use MySQL native prepared statements, which may be immune from the problem, or whether `SET NAMES` is enough for their underlying escaping mechanism to work as expected.

Regardless, if you're using any **MySQL version prior to <s>5.0.22</s> 5.0.77 and are not taking extreme care to ensure that you're only passing in strings in a known character set**, you may find yourself open to attack.

I'm leaving the rest of my original post unmodified, but I have updated the tldr.

---

> There is a lot of talk about how addslashes and mysql_real_escape function are not safe to prevent injections

This is half correct.  `addslashes` is entirely the wrong thing to use to protect against SQL injection because it is not guaranteed to provide the right escaping method for all databases, mainly because it adds backslashes and sometimes the escaping mechanism is entirely different.

If you're stuck in the ghetto of the prehistoric lump of crap known as the "mysql" extension (instead of using PDO or mysqli), `mysql_real_escape_string` is some of the best protection you've got when you need to concatenate together some SQL.

> I know there are some particular scenarios when using GBK charset, or utf8_decode can be used to inject some sql code

You're probably thinking of creating malformed UTF-8 sequences, however I've only ever seen this as an [*XSS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) mechanism, never an SQL injection mechanism.  Running strings through [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with `//IGNORE//TRANSLIT` should be good enough protection (usually by truncating the string at the point of the bad sequence, which is an acceptable failure mode *when you're being attacked* -- malformed sequences should never happen in legitimate requests).

Further, while there are plenty of "quote" characters in non-Latin languages, MySQL is pretty decent at only actually obeying the backtick and double quote for identifiers and the single quote for string values.

Thinking about it more, perhaps there's some sequence of characters in another character set that might include a single quote in the middle, if taken as a different character set.  However, it's very, very likely that `addslashes` is entirely ignorant of character set, and just works on the raw bytes.  It'd stick a backslash in the middle of a sequence, and blow it up.  However, that *should* just result in a whine somewhere along the lines about bad character set information.

`mysql_real_escape_string`, on the other hand, is designed with knowledge of the connection's character set built in, so it wouldn't escape the sequence if it sees the sequence instead of a quote.  However, because it would recognize it as a sequence instead of as a quote, there's no danger at all.

Ultimately if you think this is a problem, it's your responsibility to ensure that you accept input in only the expected character sets, and transform all input to your desired character set if there's a mismatch.  This will rarely if ever trip up a legitimate request.

---

**tl;dr:** Not a concern unless you're using a really old MySQL version and/or aren't making sure your data is in a known-good character set.  Always use database-specific escape mechanisms for maximum safetey, and always assume the user is out to get you.

Comment: What do you mean by "*assume* the user is out to get you". He **is**! ;)

Comment: mres will only secure the input 100% if you also call [`mysql_set_charset`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).  Otherwise it's susceptible to the same character set based attacks as `addslashes()`.  But if you set the charset to the connection charset, you're fine...

Comment: Hmm, in the documentation there, they suggest using that function instead of `SET NAMES ...`.  I wonder why.

Comment: I have updated my post with more information about the source of the GBK thing -- a bug in MySQL 5.0.22 and earlier.

Comment: Please note the appearance of [set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) in MySQLi, or it's procedural equivalent: mysqli_set_charset. Both since PHP 5.0.5.

Comment: Can you give an example to this vulnerability? I tried encoding `"` many different ways with UTF's variable length encoding but MySQL never decoded it as `"` to be able to use it for SQL injection.

Comment: The issue is that some character sets are *non-Unicode and multi-byte*, where one of the bytes in a legal sequence happens to be an ASCII or lower-7-bits UTF-8 quote character. That multi-byte sequence *could be* interpreted as a legal sequence by one function while interpreted as two bytes in a different character set by another.  GBK is frequently cited as one of these, where one of the multi-byte sequences includes an ASCII single quote.  (continued)

Comment: If your escaping mechanism sees the string as GBK, but MySQL thinks it's going to get ASCII or UTF-8 data, MySQL will see a single quote instead of the multi-byte sequence, and injection will occur.  Therefore, your escaping mechanism and MySQL need to see the string as the same character set.  When they see the same character set, this vulnerability can not occur. This situation can be mitigated by always making sure user input (and the data you work with) is in a single, known character set.