# Is mysql_real_escape_string() broken?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, sql-injection, prepared-statement

Some people believe that `mysql_real_escape_string()` has some flaws and cannot protect your query even when properly used.
Bringing some [fossilized articles](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html) as a proof.

So, the question is: is mysql[i]_real escape_string() totally unacceptable?
Or is it's still possible to use this function to create your own kind of prepared statements?

**With proofcode, please.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [MySQL’s C API function `mysql_real_escape_string` description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html):

> If you need to change the character set of the connection, you should use the [`mysql_set_character_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-set-character-set.html) function rather than executing a `SET NAMES` (or `SET CHARACTER SET`) statement. [`mysql_set_character_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-set-character-set.html) works like `SET NAMES` but also affects the character set used by [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-set-character-set.html), which `SET NAMES` does not.

So don’t use `SET NAMES`/`SET CHARACTER SET` but [PHP’s `mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset) to change the encoding as that is the counterpart to MySQL’s `mysql_set_character_set` (see [source code of */ext/mysql/php_mysql.c*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#L1391)).

Comment: Okay, so what happens if we're using mysqli or PDO, which don't have a native charset setting method?  Are prepared statements safe?

Comment: @Charles: MySQLi does have a corresponding function: [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset). And for prepared statements, use the [`character_set_client` system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) that is taken into account when [preparing a string type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html): “`MYSQL_TYPE_STRING` indicates character input string data. The value is assumed to be in the character set indicated by the `character_set_client` system variable.”

Comment: thanks!  PDO seems to be the only one lacking, then.  It has [a `charset` param in the DSN](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php), but it's marked as "currently ignored.."

Comment: @Charles, Does setting the charset in the connection string work? Does real_escape_string work properly by that?

Comment: @Pacerier, as of when I wrote that comment four years ago, no, it used to not work.  "DSN" == "connection string."  Since then, as noted in the linked manual page, it has been made to work.

Answer (score 8):

However, even with legacy code and old server versions, the vulnerability can only be triggered if the character set of the database connection is changed from a single-byte one like Latin-1 to a multibyte one that allows the value 0x5c (ASCII single quote) in the second or later byte of a multibyte character.

Specifically, UTF-8 does not allow that, unlike older Asian encodings like GBK and SJIS. So if your application does not change the connection character set, or changes it only to UTF-8 or single-byte ones like Latin-n, you're safe from this exploit.

But best practice is still to run the newest server version, use the correct interface to change character sets, and use prepared queries so you don't forget to escape stuff.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments there is a link to a bugfix in [mySQL 5.0.22 (24 May 2006)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/news-5-0-22.html), where this has been addressed.