# Can't update php database with a flash application

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript-3

I am having some problem here. I am trying to develop a flash database manager for my company, and I already have the insert and "search" functions working okay. The problem comes up when trying to get the UPDATE working. Ill post both codes here:

PHP (UPDATED)

```
<?php
//connect to the local MySQL
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****");

//select your database
mysql_select_db("****");

//Variables
$ID=$_POST[IDPost];

$Nome=$_POST[Nome];
$Tipo=$_POST[Tipo];
$Empresa=$_POST[Empresa];
$Morada=$_POST[Morada];
$CodPostal=$_POST[CodPostal];
$Email=$_POST[Email];
$Contacto1=$_POST[Contacto1];
$Contacto2=$_POST[Contacto2];
$DataNascimento=$_POST[DataNascimento];
$Profissao=$_POST[Profissao];
$Notas1=$_POST[Notas1];
$Notas2=$_POST[Notas2];

//query the database
$query="

UPDATE 
    GestaoClientes 
SET 
    Nome = '$Nome',
    Tipo = '$Tipo',
    Empresa = '$Empresa',
    Morada = '$Morada',
    CodPostal = '$CodPostal',
    Email = '$Email',
    Contacto1 = '$Contacto1',
    Contacto2 = '$Contacto2',
    DataNascimento = '$DataNascimento',
    Profissao = '$Profissao',
    Notas1 = '$Notas1',
    Notas2 = '$Notas2'
WHERE 
    ID = '$ID'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!mysql_query($query,$connect))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    echo "Result=NotOk";
}else{
    echo "Result=Ok";
}

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

---

Flash

```
public function editInfo(MouseEvent):void
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("link.php");
                request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
                trace("called");

                var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 

                variables.IDPost = NField.text;

                variables.Nome = NomeField.text;
                variables.Email = NomeField.text;
                variables.Morada = MoradaField.text;
                variables.CodPostal = CodPostalField.text;
                variables.Tipo = TipoField.text;
                variables.Empresa = EmpresaField.text;
                variables.Profissao = ProfissaoField.text
                variables.DataNascimento = DataNascimentoField.text;
                variables.Notas1 = Notas1Field.text;
                variables.Notas2 = Notas2Field.text;

                request.data = variables; 

                var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (request); 
                loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); 
                loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
                loader.load(request); 

            function onComplete(e:Event):void 
            {
                trace("ok");
            }
```

}

When I try going to the php in the browser if just gives me the error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Nome' = '', 'Tipo' = '', 'Empresa' = '', 'Morada' = '', 'CodPostal' = '', 'Emai' at line 4
```

This although is probably normal, since Im not passing any "POST" variables through the browser.

The flash doesent return any errors when trying this code, so I assume the connection itself is okay, but it doesent do the update either. Is there something wrong with this code? Thanks.

UPDATE: I now changed my code, and it does not show the syntax error, but still doesent update within the flash. Any ideias why? :/ thanks

Comment: you should be escape all your $_POST variables before trying to do an SQL quey with them.

Comment: What is a "PHP database"? Where is your SQL Injection prevention?

Comment: @Marco, your PHP is horrifying.  You are wide open to numerous attacks, and probably some rough data is breaking your query.  You should implement PDO for your DB work.  See http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: @Brad what he is doing can be done perfectly fine, and safely, using the `mysql_*` family of functions. There's no pressing need to switch PDO for a small Flash helper tool

Comment: I am very newby with this, and Im just trying to get it to work as easily as I can, So I have no ideia what you mean with sql injection prevention. o_o

On another note, I occulted the Database name and pass, but I believe its working, as I said, flash does not return any error when calling it, and I have already done those in INSERT and normal SELECT.

And excuse me, im just starting out, just grabbed some tuturials off the web and went from there.

Comment: @Pekka, sure, but since he is just learning, he might as well learn methods that avoid the issue (the specific issue of injection, not everything of course) altogether.  Also, see http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html

Comment: @Brad that link is outdated, the vulnerability applies only if the connection encoding isn't properly set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken plus, PDO alone will not automatically protect from every conceivable SQL injection issue and can create a false sense of security. Using it still requires  thinking, and with thinking, you can be safe with mysql_* as well. PDO is still the superior library, no doubt.

Comment: @Marco can you show the full PHP code? The query part is missing now.

Comment: Done. I pasted over that part when updated, sorry. And thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Okay, seems to be working now! Sorry for wasting your time guys, and I will take a look at SQL injections prevention when I finish the main codes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backticks instead of single quotes for column names:

```
`Nome`
```

this is the reason for the syntax error. It is also possible to use no quotes at all.

Also, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain). Read up on the issue, it's essential for security.

To fix the vulnerability at hand, do the following on every variable:

```
$Nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Nome"]);
```

and then insert the escaped variable:

```
SET `Nome` = '$Nome',
```

Comment: I have now changed the code and updated the question. Could you please take a look at it and try to see whats up with it? The query appears to have been fixed, but flash still doesent update..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a close look at [escaping your external input](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)! Inserting variables directly into your query exposes you to injection, which is an enormous security issue. ([read this](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)).

the problem you have is that you use single quotes around the field names, this is incorrect.

MySQL uses backticks ( ` ), but I do not recommend using those since they limit portability to other sql applications.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around the column names. Backticks (`) are allowed, single quotes (') are not.

I hope you realize that if your code really looks like above you have a massive security hole in your application, as anyone can execute arbitrary sql code.