# How do I make MySQL return UTF-8?

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using PHPUnit to validate XML output from my PHP code, but apparently I have problems with the character encoding [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) returns. Here is the error I get from DOMDocument:

```
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding!
Bytes: 0xE9 0x20 0x42 0x65
```

I initialize the DOMDocument so it uses the correct encoding:

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
```

And when I check the output from saveXML() using mb_detect_encoding the result is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

I also checked all the calls used to create the XML, using mb_detect_encoding on all createCDATASection parameters encountered and they are all either UTF-8 or ASCII (there are no plain text nodes, everything is in [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) blocks).

I think the issue comes from the use of an 'é' character (which is 0xE9 in [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)). The line which adds that character to my XML is:

```
$domDocument->createCDATASection($place->name);
```

and mb_detect_encoding($place->name) gives me UTF-8.

The data ($place->name) is pulled from a MySQL database. This database has the UTF-8 charset.

Here is some example code:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT name FROM place where id = 1');
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


// -- Feeding UTF-8 data directly WORKS
$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$rootNode = $domDocument->createElement('Response');
$rootNode->appendChild($domDocument->createCDATASection('Café Belga'));
$domDocument->appendChild($rootNode);

$matcher = array('tag' => 'Response');
self::assertTag($matcher, $domDocument->saveXML(), '', FALSE);

// -- Feeding UTF-8 data from the resultset FAILS
$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$rootNode = $domDocument->createElement('Response');
$rootNode->appendChild($domDocument->createCDATASection($result['name']));
$domDocument->appendChild($rootNode);

$matcher = array('tag' => 'Response');
self::assertTag($matcher, $domDocument->saveXML(), '', FALSE);
```

In my PHPStorm debugger, the string fetched from the database looks like this:

> Caf� Belga

So I think that is the root of the problem. In MySQLWorkbench the string is correct: Café Belga.

When using `utf8_encode($result['name'])`, however, everything works fine!

One more check in the watches window:

`mb_detect_encoding($result['name'])` -> "UTF-8"

`mb_detect_encoding(utf8_encode($result['name']))` -> "UTF-8"

On a side note, are there any sites where I can simply copy-paste those hex values and see what characters they are supposed to be in different character sets?

Comment: Where is the 'é' character stored? In a file? In your code?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention this, I edited my question: The data is pulled from a mysql database. This database has the utf8 charset.

Comment: @Joris do you use loadXml at any point after creating the domdocument? Also, can you provide a reproducable testcase for us that illustrates the issue?

Comment: No usage of loadXml no. I ll try making a testcase

Comment: Try adding `mysql_set_charset('utf-8');` after connecting to mysql.

Comment: @Artefacto that didn't help. Using  utf8_encode() on the string coming from my database did however

Comment: @Joris thanks for the update. This is rather an issue with your database setup than with DOMDocument or PHPUnit.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking the same now

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to define the connection to your database as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
// Set up your connection
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw');
mysql_select_db('yourdb', $connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

// Now you get UTF-8 encoded stuff
$query = sprintf('SELECT name FROM place where id = 1');
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: You should not use `SET NAMES` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken/5289141#5289141).

Comment: Thank you for that hint, Gubmo! Didn't know that

Answer (score 11):

From version PHP 5.5.0 you should use

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
```

Comment: And in object oriented fashion ie.:  $connection->set_charset("utf8mb4");