# Tiny but strong russian issue

Tags: php, collation, opentbs, tinybutstrong

Plugin Used : http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins.php
Russian characters are not displaying correctly.
In mysql database they are stored correctly collation is utf8_general_ci.

I used `define('OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8','already_utf8');`

Comment: precision:  russian variables its showing `???`

Comment: It looks like you are using the OpenTBS plug-in, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct,

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an UTF-8 problem.

You have to check that all the data chain is UTF-8 :

- all your PHP scripts
- the data injected in the template (usually a database), but you also have to check that your PHP script retrieve the data as UTF8. See « [How do I make MySQL return UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225013/how-do-i-make-mysql-return-utf-8) »
- the template (it is actually UTF8 since it is a LibreOffice or Ms Office template)

Since this chain is ok, you have to use the `OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8` option to load the template.

```
$TBS->LoadTemplate('my_template.odt', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
```

You can check that you chain is ok by a test like this :

```
echo "<!doctype html><html><head><title>Test</title><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>";
echo $my_data_from_database;
echo "</body></html>";
exit;
```

where `$my_data_from_database` is a data item retrieve from the database and that contains special characters like Russian characters.