# Converting data from utf8_unicode to utf8_general in php

Tags: php

in php I'm getting data from an utf8_unicode_ci database and storing the same into utf8_general_ci db.
That seems to be not possible when the text contains em dashes.

Does anyone know if there is a way in php to convert the data from utf8_unicode to utf8_general?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i think you have to run the query Set NAMES utf8

Comment: Don’t you rather mean *utf8\_general\_ci* instead of *utf8\_normal\_ci*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *utf8_general_ci* instead of *utf8_normal_ci* are collations of the same character encoding/set (i.e. UTF-8). An a collation does define the order and equivalence of characters:

> A difference between the collations is that this is true for *utf8_general_ci*:
>
> ```
> ß = s
> ```
>
> Whereas this is true for *utf8_unicode_ci*, which supports the German DIN-1 ordering (also known as dictionary order):
>
> ```
> ß = ss
> ```

See [Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) for more information.

So this shouldn’t have only affect operations where you compare characters/strings. Any other operation is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);

echo "The current character set is: $charset\n";
```

to check the current encoding.

and also set the character set using

Here's an improved version of Janez R.'s function:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mysql_set_charset') === false) {
    /**
     * Sets the client character set.
     *
     * Note: This function requires MySQL 5.0.7 or later.
     *
     * @see http://www.php.net/mysql-set-charset
     * @param string $charset A valid character set name
     * @param resource $link_identifier The MySQL connection
     * @return TRUE on success or FALSE on failure
     */
    function mysql_set_charset($charset, $link_identifier = null)
    {
        if ($link_identifier == null) {
            return mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET "'.$charset.'"');
        } else {
            return mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET "'.$charset.'"', $link_identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

and for utf-8

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $conn);
```

Comment: You shouldn’t do that manually. See [my answer to “Is mysql_real_escape_string() broken?”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken/5289141#5289141).