# php screws up utf-8 characters from mysql database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli, cjk

I have some Chinese characters (e.g. `中文(简体)`) stored in a mysql database with content type utf8_bin.

I am pulling from the database with this code:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT c_color FROM colors")){
   $stmt->execute();    
   $stmt->bind_result($ccolor);
   $stmt->store_result();
   if($stmt->fetch()){
       //$ccolor is filled with question marks
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?   I have

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
```

and the page is displaying Chinese characters on it.  Seems like a problem with php.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set your connection to use utf-8 aswell.
You can set it in your configuration, or set it using [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

More information: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html).

Comment: [You shouldn’t use `SET NAMES`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken/5289141#5289141)