# UTF-8 is giving me question marks

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have this simple PHP-script, which searches a mySQL database and outputs the result to the user. I used to use `ISO-8859-1` as my charset, but was advised to use `UTF-8`. But I have trouble going from my former charset to the new one.

To clarify some things, I have:

- Created a database and table encoded in `UTF-8` with collation `utf8_unicode_ci`.
- Encoded my PHP-file in `UTF-8`.
- Set meta charset to `UTF-8`.
- Set all text `mime-types` to `UTF-8` through `create-mime.assign.pl` in Lighty (Lighttpd).

Now, the problem arises when I retrieve data from the database with characters like `ö`, `ü` etc. If I just do `echo "ö";` without retrieving it from the database, it works fine. I guess there must be something wrong with the database then?

I've tried the following, and they've solved my problem:

- Set meta charset to `ISO-8859-1` (which, for some strange reason works, but breaks the echo'd "ö").
- Set a `utf8_decode()` function around the output.
- After `mysql_select_db()` declared the following `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`.

I know that I've found multiple solutions, but I just don't know why it wont work without them? And is it bad practice to use `utf8_decode()` on output, or the `mysql_set_charset()` function?

Comment: database connector as well? .. ah, nope ... yeah, you need to set the charset on the connector (`mysql_set_charset` - although this is deprecated and you should at least be using MySQLi), otherwise you'll sort of be converting the utf-8 in the database to iso 8859-1 (the default for the MySQL connector) before passing it to PHP and ultimately the screen... which will then result in '?'

Comment: @CD001 Why the hell does the MySQL connector default to ISO-8859-1? Oh well, guess that's the problem then. Will try to use fullybaked's answer below.

Comment: Heheh - yeah, I know ... try http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php or http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php although, the whole of the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated now.

Comment: I know that they're deprecated. Just have to find some time to convert my script to use `mysqli_*`. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is funny with UTF8. You need to ensure the server is running in UTF and that the connection is as well

If you can modify the my.cnf file on your server you can add these to the [mysqld] section and restart it

```
character-set-server = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

You could alternatively (or as well) use

```
query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

before sending/retrieving data to ensure the database expects UTF8 data to be passed

Comment: Will try to see if it works, if I edit the my.cnf file. By the way, the SET NAMES solution is not [recommended (or that's what I've read in multiple stackoverflow posts)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken/5289141#5289141).

Comment: There are better ways to achieve the encoding that set names, but if all else fails (or you are constrained by your hosting provider) it is a possible solution. Thats why I included it. My recommendation would be to modify the my.cnf file to properly set up the connection though.

Comment: But would `character-set-server = utf8` and `skip-character-set-client-handshake` be enough? Shouldn't I also do `default-character-set=utf8` in both [mysqld] and [client], and `character-set-client=utf8` under [mysqld]?

Comment: We only use the 2 I mentioned and pass UTF8 back and forth just fine.

Comment: The my.cnf change worked for me, thanks! I had utf8 working fully on my local host, but it wouldn't work on the production server. The connector was the missing piece.