# Why does escaping SQL values require an open connection?

Tags: php, mysqli

Just for clarity, can anyone explain why `mysqli_real_escape_string` has to read:

```
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl");
```

And not just:

```
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM tbl");
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think this question will earn you a medal if its not a duplicate

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string, its the big yellow area smacking you in the face :)

Comment: You only have to escape the input, not the whole query string.

Comment: Please learn to use *prepared statements* instead. It makes the whole idea of "escaping" obsolete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of charset encoding.

Without the `$conn`, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` won't be able to detect which character encoding the connection is using, and will blindly try to escape *common* dangerous characters - leaving some potentially dangerous charset hacks to go through.

True (not emulated) prepared statements are even better (or more secure, as you prefer), as they take the ***character encoding of the column*** instead of the connection into account.

Comment: That solves problem with `mysql_real_escape_string()` and directly changed charset in query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken

Comment: Thanks Alix Axel! Can you offer a quick explanation of prepared statements?

Comment: @RichardTinkler: This comment is too short to tell you everything about them, but they are basically prepared queries that have placeholders for the literal values. The database engine (and not the client API implementation) is responsible for replacing (and escaping) the literal values in the respective placeholders. Start by reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.