# Encoding PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I can see query results but I also see � character with some characters like "Á".

Basic connection is like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(server, user, pass, db);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
```

I also tried with:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

But characters are still watching.

Query

```
function connection($mysqli) {

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    if ( ! $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") ) {
        echo ("Error");
        return false;
    }
    if ( ! mysqli_select_db($link, "db") ) {
        echo ("Error");
        return false;
    }
    if ( ! $consulta = mysqli_query($link, $mysqli) ) {
        echo ("Error");
        return false;
    }
    return $consulta;
}
```

All files are saved with UTF8, VAR columns in DB are with UTT8 too.

What or where is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: [Don’t use `SET NAMES` for setting the character encoding.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5288953/53114)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your php file is saved as an ANSI doc, try with UTF8 without BOM.
Also try to declare the charset UTF8 on your output file.

Hope it help

Comment: All files are saved with UTF8 without BOM =S

Comment: FYI, with mysql_connect I haven't any problem:

    $sql = mysql_connect(server,user,pass);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

But, now, I have changed to mysqli and I have this problem with characters