# Mysql query works in phpmyadmin, but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

My friend has asked me about fix his old php script. I have a strange problem with it.

My query:

```
select * from users where login='Anna Jastrząb'

$login = trim($login);
$us = mysql_query("select * from users where login='$login'");
$w = mysql_fetch_array($us);
die($w['id']);
```

And it doesn't work! When I `die()` `my mysql_query` and copy it to phpmyadmin, it works.

Thanks

Comment: use mysql_fetch_array($us, MYSQL_ASSOC); n try to avoid using mysql insted use mysqli

Comment: mysql_query('set names "utf8"'); fixed my problem, lol. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '" . "$login . "'";

Comment: [You should not be using `SET NAMES` but the `mysql_set_charset` function instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5288953/53114)

Comment: You should not be using a deprecated API !!! See PHP's PDO/mysqli_ APIs and prepared statements.