# Which SQL inject methods aren't "destroyed" by mysql_real_escape_string();?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

Is there a list of SQL injection methods which can't be protected with just using `mysql_real_escape_string();` with utf8 encoding?

For integer, I'm using `intval();`
Is it secure enough?

For those who think I want to get "tutorial" to hack anyone: No, I won't. I just want to know how to make my applications more secure, and I want to know if they're secured 99% against hackers

Comment: Closely related: [Is mysql_real_escape_string() broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5288953)

Comment: @Pekka: And is there any reference WHY shouldn't I set "SET NAMES utf8" in normal mysql_query();, or just because mysql documentation recommends it ?

Comment: if mysql_real_escape_string() and the database connection assume different connections, there is the possibility of vulnerabilities under some circumstances, as explained here: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If given a valid database connection, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is supposed to be safe **for string data** under all circumstances (with the rare exception described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288953/is-mysql-real-escape-string-broken/5289141#5289141)).

However, anything outside a string, it won't escape:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id");
```

is still vulnerable, because you don't have to "break out" of a string to add an evil additional command.

Comment: @genesis generally speaking, anything outside a string - e.g. when using dynamic column or field names. Which is one reason why they are a bad idea.

Comment: and mysql_real_Escape_string(); doesn't escape  `?

Comment: @genesis nope. "mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a."

Answer (score 1):

There are not many sql injection methods. They are always due to input not being sanitized and escaped properly. So, While `mysql_real_escape_string()` will make any string safe to be included in a database query, you should follow the following avoidance techniques to protect your data and users from sql injection.

- Never connect to the database as a superuser or as the database owner. Use always customized users with very limited privileges.
- Check if the given input has the expected data type.
- If the application waits for numerical input, consider verifying data with `is_numeric()`, or silently change its type using `settype()`
- Quote each non numeric user supplied value that is passed to the database with the database-specific string escape function. So `mysql_real_escape_string()` will make all strings safe to be included in an SQL query to a mysql database
- You could also learn to use stored procedures and prepared statements which tend to be very safe but have other impacts

See also: [PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that may not get protected by standard methods (e.g. string escaping, int casting), also depending on the version of software you use. For example, utf-8 is quite an issue by itself, as a tiny example (among many) you should make sure the request is valid utf-8 (or convert it into utf-8). See an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139127/php-sql-injection-utf8-poc).

As the undead bane of websites, I think that MySQL injection protection cannot be squeezed into a single SO answer, hence I'm including these links as general starting points.

http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/

And also : [Search for mysql injection utf8](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=mysql%20injection%20utf8)

Comment: I'm having trouble collectiing an answer from these resources. Can you elaborate?

Comment: yes @pekka, me too ... it's nice for global knowledge, but I'm asking for more specified thing